# jquery ajax not catching error when posting to an aspx page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/zzz/bbb/abcd.aspx?deleteIDs=" + request_ids,
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
data: '',
dataType: "html",
complete: function(xhr, status) { 

    if (status == "success") 
    {
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

The jquery code above has its status ="success" regardless of the outcome of the background operation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Success" only refers to the response from the server.  If the server response is a 200 response, it will be considered a success, no matter if the business logic on the server side encountered an issue.

You can either return a 400 or 500 error code from the server, or preferably, you send a response back to the JS that contains any error messages.

For example, I usually expect a JSON response from the server.  If there was an error on the server side, it contains an error:true flag and I handle it in the JS.  So a typical errorless response would be:

```
{error:false, html:"My HTML in here"}
```

An error on the server would return:

```
{error:true, errorMsg: "My error message here"}
```

EDITed to give an example:

Expecting a JSON response as outlined above, I could do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.error) { alert(data.errorMsg); }
        else {
            //do something with data.html
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. So should I parse through the response body and look for some custom message that I could send from the asp.net application?

Comment: @developer747, steve's answer is absolutely correct. your data that is returned in from the parameter(s) of your success function could vary quite a lot depending on how the ajax endpoint was designed. you should also start by console.log'ing your response param and seeing what exactly is inside of it. once you know for sure, you can parse it and start iterating through it by namespace and property.

Comment: using dataType: "json" and then using success and failure events solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

If that code is exactly what you're using, there is an error in the url field: you open the line with double quotes, and end it with a single quote.

Comment: sorry, I had edited the url before posting it here. Fixed the quote error.